# Save list of files to text file

Tags: linux, kali-linux

Apparently this command should work (list of files from `/bin` folder):

```
ls /bin > /root/test1/test2/filelist.txt
```

I get:

```
No such file or directory /root/test1/test2/filelist.txt
```

I'm definitely making some obvious mistake but I have never understood Linux so I will never figure it out on my own.

Comment: Now it says that there is no such file or directory. So at least something happens, but not exactly what should happen.

Comment: What file or directory does it say this about? Please be specific. Do not respond in comments, [edit] the question.

Comment: No such file or directory /root/test1/test2/filelist.txt

Comment: Please read answers to [this question](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5360/108618). It's not a brickbat; it's an attempt to make your learning process easier. Your current problem would be the same in any Linux, but if you are unfamiliar to this degree then sooner or later you will suffer in Kali more than in some other Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting the `No such file or directory` error most likely because the directory you're trying to create the file in doesn't exist.

Create the directory first using:

```
mkdir -p /root/test1/test2
```

And then try again.

```
root@rubiks:~# mkdir -p /root/test1/test2
root@rubiks:~# ls /bin >/root/test1/test2/filelist.txt
root@rubiks:~# head /root/test1/test2/filelist.txt
GET
HEAD
NF
POST
VGAuthService
X
X11
Xephyr
Xorg
Xwayland
```

---

As stated in the comments, there is the assumption that:

> Nothing inside /home/kali/Desktop/test1/test2. I have been told this
> path equals /root/test1/test

Unless you have created a symlink (which I highly doubt), this assertion is wrong. Paths are unique on Unix based systems and the first path is **not** the other.

---

Given the nature of your question and your own assertion that you don't "understand Linux", I'm also slightly wondering *why* you're using Kali Linux. [As Kali's developers state](https://www.kali.org/docs/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux/):

> The fact of the matter is, however, that Kali is a Linux distribution
> specifically geared towards professional penetration testers and
> security specialists, and given its unique nature, it is NOT a
> recommended distribution if you’re unfamiliar with Linux or are
> looking for a general-purpose Linux desktop distribution for
> development, web design, gaming, etc.

This is good advice. Kali Linux is not for the faint of heart, it's a very specific distro with a very specific use case and things that are easy in Ubuntu, Fedora or Mint are a *major* hassle on Kali. You might want to get some experience using Linux based systems on a distro that's easier to use (the aforementioned).

Comment: No errors now, but filelist.txt still seem to be missing. Nothing inside /home/kali/Desktop/test1/test2. I have been told this path equals /root/test1/test2